# I have problems with executing a while loop

Tags: while-loop

i <- 1
while(i<10){
print(i)
i<-i+1
if(i==4){
next
}
}

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
```

I execute this code, but still have number 4 in my result although I am using "next" in my code to skipp it

Comment: what is your programming language ?

Comment: @VenkataramanR I am using RStudio

Answer (score 0):

use the following instead.

if(i!=4){print(i)}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

or you wanted to test with next, use print after next

{
if(i==4){next}
print(i)
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).